# Make a non-nested div not jump at window resize

Tags: html, css

I have a div box that in the HTML code is below all the other content and not nested into anything else. In the CSS I placed the div on the top right of the site, and when I change the window size so that it doesn't fit, it jumps down on the site. I am not allowed to change the HTML code (it's a school assignment).

Is there any way I can make this jumping div box stay in place relative to the main content?

In the div box I have placed a background picture because this is the only way to add a stand-alone picture without changing the HTML. The teachers added these extra div-boxes in the code just for this.

The div's CSS (if it helps):

```
#extraDiv1 {
    background-image: url('images/koala.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 370px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: -610px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: It's very long so I don't know how to do that in a good way. :/

Comment: sorry. there's not much I can do without it though. maybe just try posting the relevant part? or make a jsfiddle and link to that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `top` and `left` attributes to position your box properly.  Since you're using relative positioning, this will position it relative to its normal position.  Therefore, if you want to line it up with where you said you want it, you would end up with something like this:

```
#extraDiv1 {
    background-image: url('images/koala.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 370px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    border: 3px solid red;
    top: -610px;
    left: 660px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I remove the float: left, the div sticks to the top left corner of the browser. I want it to be aligned with the content (which is centered to the page) so that they move together.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle with the full html and css? right now I'm not exactly sure what you're talking about

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dYZdR/1/ I want the red bordered box to be above the two side-boxes, acting exactly as the side boxes are.

Comment: That didn't work, because now it is stuck in place if you make the browser window bigger. I want it to follow the other content (always be above the side boxes even when making the window bigger or smaller) and not stick in place to the background.

Comment: what are you making bigger? you could just use a percentage instead of a specific pixel value for `left`